# Android translate ImageView animation doesn't work properly

Tags: android, animation, android-imageview, translate-animation

I would like to translate an ImageView on the vertical ax and then on the horizontal one.

Here is my translate.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="180%"
        android:fromXDelta="50%"
        android:toXDelta="50%"
        android:duration="1500">
    </translate>

    <translate
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-200%"
        android:duration="1500">
    </translate>



    </set>
```

The code from Myactivity.java:

ImageView Img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);

```
anim_translate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),translate);

//load animation
Img1.startAnimation(anim_translate);
```

I would like the image to move down, and THEN translate to left, but it only moves to the left corner, one time.
thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to separate this into two animations? You can register a listener when the first animation is finished and then you would start the second animation.

Comment: It's solved now, thank you! I added an android:startOffset for every part of the animation.

Comment: You can share the final solution so that anyone else can use it :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
<translate 
    android:fromYDelta="0%" 
    android:toYDelta="170%" 
    android:fromXDelta="50%" 
    android:toXDelta="50%" 
    android:duration="1500" 
    android:fillAfter="true"> 
</translate> 

<translate 
    android:startOffset="1500" 
    android:fillAfter="true" 
    android:fromXDelta="0%" 
    android:toXDelta="-200%" 
    android:duration="1500"> 
</translate>
```